# Workflow foundation 4.0 request-response in long running process

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

What is the simplest way to solve the following in WF 4.0:

- Send data/request to a WCF service (for example a request to start process X)
- Get a response (simple, success/failure of deserializing the input) only indicating that processing has started.
- Continue processing (could potentially take a few minutes) in a custom WF activity
- End

My goal is to have the response sent back to the WCF client as soon as the object is received, and handle any processing without the client waiting. Currently, my sequential workflow locks until the custom activity is completed before continuing.

Comment: Have you tried to use Parallel activity to branch those two steps? One branch for the response and another for the heavy processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggested workaround is to add a wait activity after the response activity with f.ex. a timespan of 1 second or more. This will force sending of the response, and after 1 second continue the execution.

I would not call this a solution, but might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the request to a 'OneWay' method in WCF to kick off the processing;

> [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]

While this does not send back a response, it could be assumed that unless a Fault has been raised, the process has started. If you need to indicate that if failed, just throw something.

Another method could then be polled to check the status of the intital request. Alternatively, you could use WCF callbacks.

An introduction into some of these concepts [What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

Comment: IsOneWay = true indicates the WCF operation has no response.  It sounds like he does want a response indicating the request was received.

Comment: Good point (post updated), however if no error is received from the call, you could assume it has been successful. Raise a FaultException if not.

Comment: I would like to return a response object of my choosing yes. I am adding my temporary workaround as a answer to my own post.